# Converting days (datetime) to integer in python?

Tags: python

I can't convert days(datetime) to int? I believe it is because int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object, or a number and it can't because it is not 'NoneType'.

However, I couldn't find a way out to convert this to integer? How can this be done without getting things complicated? I wish it could be done with just int()... :(

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from dateutil import parser

    diff = now - obj['LastModified']
    daysLeft_to_delete = 1000 - int(diff)
```

Error output: "errorMessage": "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'",

P.S: Diff defines day number. e.g: 30,50,20...

Comment: "datetime.timedelta" is a method, not a string. To convert it to integer, I guess that first converting it to a string and then to an integer would work properly. Try this code out:

`int(str(datetime.timedelta))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for difference in days, `Timedelta` objects have `.days` property:

```
daysLeft_to_delete = 1000 - diff.days
```